# How can I add radio from another site to mine

Tags: web, internet-radio

So I want to add a radio from another site, so that people can play it on my site. How can I do that?
I really don't know what to do and I don't even know how to search. I have tried to search but couldn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

Try an iframe tag to copy the "player" onto your website

Tbh we need more information, preferably a example of what you're trying to copy will be the best.

Edit:

```
<iframe src="http://graaz.tv/wp-content/plugins/shoutcast-icecast-html5-radio-player/html5/html5icecast-350.php?id=10&rand=2"></iframe>
```

That is it according to your link.

You can adjust the size refer to this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

Comment: This is the player I'm trying to add. [link](http://graaz.tv/wp-content/plugins/shoutcast-icecast-html5-radio-player/html5/html5icecast-350.php?id=10&rand=2)